# Is Q capable of travelling to mirror universes and/or fluidic space?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-q, mirror-universe

Are the Q capable of travelling to mirror universes, alternate universes and/or fluidic space?

Comment: Of course.  Why not?

Comment: I don't ever remember seeing any Q travel beyond the normal universe.  Q can create matter from nothing, create lifeforms and travel to anywhere in the universe, but I don't remember any kind evidence that they could leave the universe.

Comment: I would think so, considering that they can [travel to the Big Bang](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Death_Wish_(episode)#Act_Two).

Comment: The Big Bang is in this universe though, correct?

Comment: I shouldn't say the Big Bang is in this universe, I guess I should say it is this universe.

Comment: I would imagine that the Q-equivalents of those other universes don't take too kindly to the intrusion.

Comment: I imagine there probably aren't any Q in fluidic space, at the least most Q would probably find it too boring to even travel there.  Still it is interesting to think about.

Comment: @Caimen re: "The Big Bang is in this universe". If Trek mirror universes are quantum in nature (I don't know) then our big bang could be shared with them, and so travelling to it would be partially like travelling to them.

Comment: Q being able to travel from universe to universe could bring about some interesting problems.  Would Q (individual) be able to just simply go meet all his likenesses across all the universes?  Would there by definition be infinite Q?

Comment: I think that if Q exists outside space-time, then there's probably only 1 Q who exists across all those universes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could probably make a reasonable argument that Q is creating and entering alternate universes when he does things like transport the cast of TNG into Robin Hood, so it might follow that he should be able to travel to other universes as well.

Also, Q can travel through time. If parallel universes branch at every possibility, and they all ARE happening, there doesn't seem to be any reason why he wouldn't be able to follow one path or another, given the nature of his power. It seems to follow that a being that can travel through time could at the very least enter an alternate universe merely by traveling to the moment of choice, changing the choice that was made, and then moving forward again.

That said, there is no canonical example of Q popping up in anything that the characters refer to as an alternate or a mirror universe. The idea of alternate universes sees relatively little exploration in Star Trek, though.

Comment: I always assumed that Q was creating these worlds within the same universe, perhaps at very far points from where the characters originated, but far enough away to where no sentient being could find the strange world Q had created. Based upon the fact that Q can just as easily create matter and life, there is really little reason to suspect that he would travel to an alternate universe just to create these little diversions for the Enterprise crew.  But that's pure speculation on my part. The time travel part of your argument certainly deserves great consideration.

Comment: That's a very good point. I always assume that Q is genuinely going back and inserting himself and others into Earth's history, because I think that part of the idea of Q is to have someone who is using really immense godly powers for really petty childish things, but perhaps he's all show. ;)

Comment: If Q knows about it... It's hard to believe that Q knows of every possible universe. Didn't Spock say that there are infinite universes? If they are then it's impossible to know of all of them, hence the nature of infinity.

Answer (score 5):

"Junior" Q mentions going to fluidic space in the Voyager episode Q2. So I'd think fluidic space doesn't seem a problem for Q.

Comment: That is awesome.  I went and looked up the script and this is what he said exactly.  "JUNIOR: We could fly into fluidic space and fight species 8472. Or we could detonate a few Omega molecules. What do you say?", "JANEWAY: No."   http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/716.htm

Comment: To be fair, Q does not need to use his powers to go into fluidic space. Voyager can do it. Therefore this is not proof that he _can_ use his powers to go there.